# How can I manipulate shapes in Adobe Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, shapes

I'm working on an application where I'm drawing some rectangles on the screen, and then will need to manipulate the shapes (change their size, location).  I tried to do something with .drawRect and clearing the shape each time I was manipulating it, but the RAM usage was spiking and then falling (presumeably because i keep reinitializing a new component and then removing it, and garbage collection was cleaning it out).  This seems like its probably not the most efficient way to do it.

Is there a way for me to just create a shape once, and then move it around on a canvas (and change its width and height without all this RAM usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're doing is changing it's offsets, and adjusting it's width and height without needing to fundamentally change the structure of the shape (such as rounding the corners of a rectangle of some such)  you should be able to just maintain a reference to the Shape and adjust it's x, y, scaleX, scaleY properties to effect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Degrafa](https://code.google.com/p/degrafa/) to draw the rectangle.

To move the rectangle:

- Changing the x and y or height and width property of the shape
- Using the Flex Move Effect